# Remove punctuation after preg_split and capitalize the words with more than two letters

Tags: php

I have this preg_split to split the text after the punctuation marks.

```
$content = preg_split('/(?<=[!?.])./', $content);
```

**Problem 1**. Ineed a way to split the text but remove punctuation other that question mark.

How can I do this?

**Problem 2.** Is there a way to capitalize the words which have more than two letters? Right now I use CSS but text-transform: capitalize does it on every word, even 1 letter words and this makes it look funky on the page. This is why I am thinking of using php to do this.

Ty very much,
Hope you can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem 1:

If you need to split on every pontuation marks but can't replace on question mark, you need to do it in two steps, because `preg_replace` would replace your question mark too.

You should split first then replace(by "") after that.

Is your regex working as expected ? The first part `(?<=)` seems weird according to your problem. I guess just `/!\?\\./` would do the trick.

Problem 2:

I would split your phrases using space then iterate over the resulting array(the words) then checking the size of each word, capitalizing it if it's size is bigger than 1.